# how do i allow my listview to be stored so that i can pull to display from another class or form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, instance

```
{
public partial class BookNow : Form
{
    private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
    private string title;
    private string ad;  //Adult
    private string ch;  //Child
    private string sd;  //StartDate
    private string rd;  //ReturnDate
    private string ins; //Insurance
    private string extb; //Extra Baggage
    private int people;
    private double total = 0;
    Cart c = new Cart();
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(30);


    public BookNow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        adult.SelectedIndex = 1;
        child.SelectedIndex = 0;
        insuranceNo.Checked = true;
        tenKG.Checked = true;
    }

    private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tour.Text == "Choose A Tour")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a tour of your choice", "Choice of Tour Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            tour.Focus();
        }
        else if (adult.Text == "0" && child.Text == "0")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select number of Travellers", "Number of Travellers Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            adult.Focus();
        }
        else if (startDate.Text == returnDate.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Start Date and Return Date Cannot be the Same. Please Edit Dates to Continue", "Dates Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            returnDate.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            if (tour.Text == "TSIN - Singapore's Discovery")
                total += 1299.00;
            else if (tour.Text == "TSEO - Seoul's Highlights")
                total += 1899.00;
            else if(tour.Text == "TTAI - Taiwan Spotlight")
                total += 1000.00;

                title = tour.Text;
                ad = adult.Text;
                ch = child.Text ;
                sd = startDate.Text;
                rd = returnDate.Text;
            if (insuranceYes.Checked)
            {
                ins += insuranceYes.Text;
                total += 29.99;
            }
            else
            {
                ins = insuranceNo.Text;
            }

            if (tenKG.Checked)
                extb = tenKG.Text;
            else if (twentyKG.Checked)
            {
                extb = twentyKG.Text;
                total += 50.00;
            }
            else
            {
                extb = thirtyKG.Text;
                total += 80.00;
            }
            people = int.Parse(ad) + int.Parse(ch);
            total = total * people;
            cartNow(c);
            total = 0;
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Added To Cart, Continue To Your Cart?","Cart Updated",  MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                c.add(c);
                Hotel h = new Hotel();
                h.Show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Cart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c.Show();
    }
```

> This method is to Add into my listview so that i can display and i tried using an array but still unable to do it

```
    public void cartNow (Cart instance)
    {
        ListViewItem lvl = new ListViewItem(arr[0].ToString());
        lvl.SubItems.Add(arr[1].ToString());
        lvl.SubItems.Add(ch);
        lvl.SubItems.Add(sd);
        lvl.SubItems.Add(rd);
        lvl.SubItems.Add(ins);
        lvl.SubItems.Add(extb);
        lvl.SubItems.Add(total.ToString("c2"));
        instance.listView1.Items.Add(lvl);

    }

    private void Close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var confirmResult = MessageBox.Show("Closing the booking System will result in clearing the Cart.","Are You sure you want to continue?",
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (confirmResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        }
    }

    public void showCart()
    {
        c.Show();
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
            myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
            return myCp;
        }
    }
}
}
```

> I am able to open up my Cart and display the items inside my listview but when i close the cart and want to run from another form it does not work as the information becomes empty e.g(variable ad which has the number of adults becomes null and nth will be displayed if i try to run the cartNow() method from another class

Comment: My code is not well done as i'm still learning so don't mind it

Comment: This current form will hide and show Hotel Form but i want to show whatever i have shown in my listview in cart to be there too but whenever i do that the information will be blank

Comment: My goal is to create a Booking Page and users are able to add to cart and view their cart and at the same time see what they have added and can remove orders that they dont want, i have done everything up till hotel where i am unable to show the Cart information again but if i view my cart at the Booking Page my cart information will be there (P.S both are two different form)